# How to update a control in MDI parent form from child forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mdi

I looked to some similar questions but I didn't really get my answer, so I ask again hopefuly someone can explain it.

The situation:

I have a MDI form that has some menues and a status bar and stuff like that. Is the only way of altering text for status bar and doing other things to the parent form is to call it as `static`? Or if not, can you please give an example for updating (for example) status bar that exist in parent form within the child forms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use events (you can build these events into a base class and let all your child forms inherit from it):

```
// Code from Form 1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
        objForm2.ChangeStatus += new ChangeStatusHandler(objForm2_ChangeStatus);
        objForm2.Show();
    }
    public void objForm2_ChangeStatus(string strValue)
    {
        statusbar.Text = strValue;
    }
}

// Code From Form 2
public delegate void ChangeStatusHandler(string strValue);
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event ChangeStatusHandler ChangeStatus;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PassValue != null)
        {
            PassValue(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the child forms take a parent form instance as a constructor parameter.
The children can save this parameter to a private field, then interact with the parent at will later.

For optimal design, you should abstract the parent from the child through an interface implemented by the parent, containing methods and properties that do what the children need.  The children should then only interact with this interface.

```
public interface IChildHost {
    void UpdateStatusBar(string status);
    //Other methods & properties
}

public partial class ParentForm : IChildHost {
    public void UpdateStatusBar(string status) {
        ...
    }
    //Implement other methods & properties
}

public partial class ChildForm {
    readonly IChildHost host;
    public ChildForm(IChildHost parent) {
        this.host = parent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give example? do you mean like in parent form instantisize like `ChildForm child = new ChildForm(this)` and in `ChildForm` Constructor to do like `ChildForm(Form parent)` ?!

Comment: Exactly, except that the child forms should take a parameter of type `ParentForm` (or, better yet, `IChildHost`), not `Form`.

Comment: sorry but I think I need to see some code to understand this well :( would you mind some codes please?

Comment: @SLaks: Isn't this already covered with the concept of MDIParent? If he uses a base class for his forms (driven by an interface as you suggest), he should be able to interact both ways.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Yes, but that's more coupled.  My version allows you to use the children without MDI using a different `IChildHost`.

Comment: @Slaks: Ok, I can see that. If there is no intention of using a form outside of the MDI relationship, does this method hold any benefits over the stricter coupling?

Comment: @Slaks: In asking the question in my comment, I'm not disagreeing with your answer, I'm actually interested in any potential benefits for either one.

Comment: It makes the child form easier to construct, but it creates a hidden dependency on the MdiParent.

Answer (score 3):

The [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) class already exposes a property [MdiParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx) ensure the parent forms [IsMdiContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer.aspx) property is set accordingly.